# How to change image paths in Redactor editor?

Tags: redactor, craftcms

I use Redactor editor in CraftCMS for blog posts. When I insert images in Redactor the URLs are wrong(relative paths) on details blog page and even in Redactor editor in CMS, missing a / before the upload directory where the images are uploaded.

How can I add a slash at the beginning of URLs or set them to use absolute paths?

The URL for blog posts looks like www.website.com/blog/post-name

This is my json config for Redactor:

```
{
  "buttons": ["formatting", "bold", "italic", "unorderedlist", "orderedlist", "link", "image", "video", "html"],
  "plugins": ["fullscreen", "video"],
  "linkNewTab": true,
  "toolbarFixed": true,
  "imageFigure": false,
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should check that your Redactor field is set up to use your image asset volumes:[image: settings for a Redactor field in Craft CMS]

If it is then the issue is not with Redactor, but with the settings for your asset volume. File system paths to images, and their URLs are determined by the settings on your asset volume:[image: asset volume settings in Craft CMS]